# mysql error #1062 - Duplicate entry UPDATE column

Tags: mysql

When i tring to update whole column in mysql i get this error

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '74-0-1-0' for key 'product_sqlstock'
```

Mysql query

```
UPDATE `ps_stock_available` SET `id_product_attribute`= '0'
```

how can I update id_product_attribute column?

Comment: Post `SHOW CREATE TABLE ps_stock_available` You are violating a unique index.

Comment: @user3588722 where's the "where" clause for update?

Comment: @user3588722 Do you want to set all rows in your column that seems to have a unique index to the special value NULL?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `ps_stock_available` SET `id_product_attribute`= '0' 
WHERE `id_product_attribute`= '1'
```

You have to add a where clause telling it which you would like to replace. Replace the one with the value you want to change.